# Save and load table view from JSON file?

Tags: json, swift, uitableview

I'm sorry this questions won't perfectly to conform to what stack overflow wants questions to look like, but I have a general questions about a programming technique.

In my case, the user can manually add and edit his table view cells. After he's finished editing it, is it possible to "save" the resulting table view into a JSON file? 
I want it to upload then to firebase, so that another user can download it, read the data from the JSON file and have the same view controller in front of him.

How is that possible? Is that possible? And if not, which "technique" would you use for doing it?

Comment: You should be trying to separate UI (table views, cells) from data as much as possible. Presumably, your table view gets its data from something - some backing array or dictionary of data. That is what you should be saving and loading via JSON.

Answer (score 1):

The data in a UITableView is backed by a UITableViewDataSource.  The class you write to implement this just provides cells on demand from some data.  It could also provide JSON.

So, it's not the table that does this, but instead the class you implement to fill the table with data.

Answer (score 0):

You can save things with core data. 
Building a JSON file is not hard.
Try this links

http://www.appcoda.com/fetch-parse-json-ios-programming-tutorial/
http://maniacdev.com/2013/04/library-for-integrating-web-services-turning-json-data-into-core-data-backed-native-objects

Comment: Don't use UserDefaults to store JSON or any data. It's made for storing small things, not the contents of tableViews.